# Scipy sparse memory explosion with simple matrix multiplication

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I noted that Scipy must be storing some intermediate arrays when doing matrix multiplication. I assume this can be helpful in some cases, but it is a pain sometimes. Consider the following example:

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
n = 100000000000
row  = np.array([0, 0])
col  = np.array([0, n-1])
data = np.array([1, 1])
A = coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(2, n))
```

Yes, this is a very large matrix. However it has only two nonzero values. The result of `B = A.dot(A.T)` can be evaluated by hand since it has only one nonzero value. The matrix `B` is such that `B[0, 0] = 2` and zero elsewhere. When I try to run this I get Memory Error, you can see the Traceback below:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-3e0d3e3c3f13> in <module>
----> 1 A.dot(A.T)

~/anaconda3/envs/tfx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py in dot(self, other)
    361 
    362         """
--> 363         return self * other
    364 
    365     def power(self, n, dtype=None):

~/anaconda3/envs/tfx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py in __mul__(self, other)
    479             if self.shape[1] != other.shape[0]:
    480                 raise ValueError('dimension mismatch')
--> 481             return self._mul_sparse_matrix(other)
    482 
    483         # If it's a list or whatever, treat it like a matrix

~/anaconda3/envs/tfx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py in _mul_sparse_matrix(self, other)
    538 
    539     def _mul_sparse_matrix(self, other):
--> 540         return self.tocsr()._mul_sparse_matrix(other)
    541 
    542     def __rmul__(self, other):  # other * self

~/anaconda3/envs/tfx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py in _mul_sparse_matrix(self, other)
    494 
    495         major_axis = self._swap((M, N))[0]
--> 496         other = self.__class__(other)  # convert to this format
    497 
    498         idx_dtype = get_index_dtype((self.indptr, self.indices,

~/anaconda3/envs/tfx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py in __init__(self, arg1, shape, dtype, copy)
     35                 arg1 = arg1.copy()
     36             else:
---> 37                 arg1 = arg1.asformat(self.format)
     38             self._set_self(arg1)
     39 

~/anaconda3/envs/tfx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py in asformat(self, format, copy)
    324             # Forward the copy kwarg, if it's accepted.
    325             try:
--> 326                 return convert_method(copy=copy)
    327             except TypeError:
    328                 return convert_method()

~/anaconda3/envs/tfx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/coo.py in tocsr(self, copy)
    402             col = self.col.astype(idx_dtype, copy=False)
    403 
--> 404             indptr = np.empty(M + 1, dtype=idx_dtype)
    405             indices = np.empty_like(col, dtype=idx_dtype)
    406             data = np.empty_like(self.data, dtype=upcast(self.dtype))

MemoryError:
```

The output is a 2 x 2 matrix, so it doesn't matter if it is dense or not. What the program is trying to do to cause this failure at such simple problem? How can I fix this behavior?

Thank you.

Comment: Just an extra comment: The program should've "know" that only the first and last columns can have nonzero values. This is possible to infer from the given coordinates when defining A. Therefore I can't see why the number of columns would change anything.

Comment: Show the **full** traceback.

Comment: Try `A.tocsr()` and `A.tocsr().T` by themselves.  The transpose should be a a `csc` matrix,

Comment: I tried both and none of them causes the memory explosion.

Comment: Try `(A.T).tocsr()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COO is a format that does not lend itself well to math for reasons I will leave to the reader.

In this edge condition case, I think you would be best-served by solving the problem directly:

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
import numpy as np

n = 100000000000
row  = np.array([0, 0])
col  = np.array([0, n-1])
data = np.array([1, 1])
A = coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(2, n))

B = A.tocsr()
C = A.tocsr().T

n, m = B.shape[0], C.shape[1]
out_arr = np.zeros((n, m), dtype=A.dtype)

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        out_arr[i, j] = B[i, :].multiply(C[:, j].T).data.sum()
```

For any problem with a reasonably small `n` & `m` this workaround will be sufficient.

Comment: That's a very nice solution. You are right it is a edge case, still I think it would be interesting if Scipy had a special dot function as the one you showed.

Comment: The limitation in scipy is that the dot product code does not accept `CSC` matrices (I don't think that there's a strong push to update some of the sparse matrix code in scipy because of how far ahead the math kernel library has gotten). It's faster to calculate `CSR` (dot) `CSC` anyway, and restricting the dot function to `CSR` actually creates a couple problems of which this is only one.

Answer (score 2):

If you look into the source code, you'll find that eventually `A.T` (the operand of `dot` in `A.dot(A.T)`) is converted to a `csr_matrix`, and that matrix has an attribute called `indptr` that has length `n+1`.  With your value of `n`, `indptr` for that `csr_matrix` will require hundreds of gigabytes of memory.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. Now, it should have a way around this right? I don't mean to write a code but the Scipy guys must know this.

Comment: Yes, this conversion is evident in the full traceback.   Evidently the sparse multiplication is written to handle the most general cases, and doesn't take special steps to address cases like yours.

Comment: I think it would be weird to not have a function or option ready to deal with this kind of problem. The inputs are small, the output is small, and the middle is able to be small.

Comment: *"Now, it should have a way around this right?"*  I'm not sure about that.  The scipy code should never "densify" a sparse matrix, but it will be pretty flexible about converting between different sparse formats, without considering the possibility that a particular format might "blow up" memory usage.

Comment: It doesn't need to densify anything. Anyone is able to compute the result by hand without the need to consider the gazillion zeros inside the original matrix.

Comment: *"It doesn't need to densify anything."*  Right, and that's why I said won't densify it. (OK, I said it "should never" do it, and in fact, it won't.)  Converting `A.T` to CSR format isn't "densifying".  That conversion will, however, run out of memory.

Comment: Indeed, and now I assume no one considered a scenario where the COO format would be better (like the one showed here). My second question was about this: if there is a dot specifically for COO format, that would be able to perform this multiplication without memory error.

Comment: Years ago sparse formats were developed by mathematicians to handle linear algebra problems like finite difference and finite element. Math with the `csr` and `csc` formats works well for that. I believe MATLAB still only uses `csc`, `coo` has little math, not even indexing.