# scipy super sparse matrix multiplication is super slow

Tags: numpy, sparse-matrix

There are some posts on SO discussing sparse matrix multiplication performance, but they don't seem to answer my question here.

Here is the benchmark code,

```py
# First, construct a space matrix
In [1]: from scipy.sparse import dok_matrix
In [2]: M = dok_matrix((100, (1<<32)-1), dtype=np.float32)
In [3]: rows, cols = M.shape
In [5]: js = np.random.randint(0, (1<<32)-1, size=100)
In [6]: for i in range(rows):
   ...:     for j in js:
   ...:         M[i,j] = 1.0
   ...:

# Check out sparsity
In [7]: M.shape
Out[7]: (100, 4294967295)
In [8]: M.count_nonzero()
Out[8]: 10000

# Test csr dot performance, 36.3 seconds
In [9]: csr = M.tocsr()
In [10]: %time csr.dot(csr.T)
CPU times: user 36.3 s, sys: 1min 1s, total: 1min 37s
Wall time: 1min 46s
Out[10]:
<100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float32'>'
    with 10000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

The above `csr.dot` costs 36.3s, which is quite long IMHO.
In order to speed up, I coded up a naive for-loop dot function as follows,

```py
def lil_matmul_transposeB(A, B):
    rows_a, cols_a = A.shape
    rows_b, cols_b = B.shape
    assert cols_a == cols_b
    C = np.zeros((rows_a, rows_b))

    for ra in range(rows_a):
        cols_a = A.rows[ra]
        data_a = A.data[ra]
        for i, ca in enumerate(cols_a):
            xa = data_a[i]
            for rb in range(rows_b):
                cols_b = B.rows[rb]
                data_b = B.data[rb]
                pos = bs(cols_b, ca)
                if pos!=-1:
                    C[ra,rb] += data_b[pos] * xa
    return C

# Test dot performance in LiL format,
In [25]: lil = M.tolil()
In [26]: %time A = F.lil_matmul_transposeB(lil, lil)
CPU times: user 1.26 s, sys: 2.07 ms, total: 1.26 s
Wall time: 1.26 s
```

The above function only costs 1.26s, much faster than the built-in `csr.dot`.

So I wonder if I made some mistakes here to do the sparse matrix multiplication?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63106851/scipy-sparse-memory-explosion-with-simple-matrix-multiplication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That very large 2nd dimension is giving problems, even though the sparsity is quite small.

```
In [12]: Mr = M.tocsr()
In [20]: Mr
Out[20]: 
<100x4294967295 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float32'>'
    with 10000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Transpose just turns the `csr` into `csc`, without changing the arrays.  That `indptr` for both is just (101,).

```
In [21]: Mr.T
Out[21]: 
<4294967295x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float32'>'
    with 10000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
```

But when I do `Mr@Mr.T`, I get an error when it tries to convert that `Mr.T` to `csr.  That is, the multiplication requires the same format:

```
In [22]: Mr.T.tocsr()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-22-a376906f557e>", line 1, in <module>
    Mr.T.tocsr()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/csc.py", line 138, in tocsr
    indptr = np.empty(M + 1, dtype=idx_dtype)
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 32.0 GiB for an array with shape (4294967296,) and data type int64
```

It's trying to make a matrix with a `indptr` that's (4294967296,) long.  On my limited RAM machine that produces an error.  On your's it must be hitting some sort of memory management/swap task that slowing it way down.

So it's the extreme dimension that's making this slow even though the `nnz` is small.

Comment: Thanks so much for spending time doing a detailed analysis on this!! Yes, the 2nd dim is quite large, and actually I don't understand why it would cost so much RAM given such a few non-zero elements.

Comment: Also if I may add one more observation, the `scipy.sparse.random` will first create a huge list of indices, and then sample from it to create a fake sparse matrix, and that's quite RAM greedy, and cannot work for my 2nd dim (i.e. ipython shell killed by OS)

Comment: Yes, the was a recent SO about that random generator - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64849974/initialize-high-dimensional-sparse-matrix.  The method of choosing random indicies uses a simple `choice` over all possible values.  It's a naive approach that works fine for modest test matrices.